# How do I make a request within a route and respond only when I have the response data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I've been told to use axios but it's asynchronous and will respond before the inner POST request is complete:

```js
var express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios').default;
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    axios({
        url: "https://example.com/api",
        method: "POST",
        data: "Some data"
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response) // I want to return this
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error) // or this
    })
    res.send("Response or error data here")
});

module.exports = router;
```

Is there a synchronous module I should use?

Comment: Send the response *from the callback*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: If I add a `res.send()` within the `then()` it doesn't ork because it's async and skips to the `res.send()` outside of the post request.

Comment: Of course, that's why you don't put *any* res.send outside the promise chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass either response or error to `res.json` when the axios promise is resolved/rejected:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  axios({
    url: "https://example.com/api",
    method: "POST",
    data: "Some data"
  }).then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  }).catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
var express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios').default;
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    axios({
        url: "https://example.com/api",
        method: "POST",
        data: "Some data"
    }).then(response => {
        console.log() // I want to return this
        res.send(response)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error) // or this
        res.status(500).send({
            message: e.message || "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
        });
    })
    
});

module.exports = router;
```

The `res` object has scope within the closure of callback you supply in your `.then()`, so you could call the `res.send` method from there. Also, make sure to respond with something in the `.catch()` so if an error occurs, your API responds with something, instead of getting stuck and timing out.

**NOTE**: The reason I made an object with a `message` instead of responding with the `error` object itself, is that I don't know what I may get in `error`. For instance, if it is an instance of the `Error` class then there may be trouble in the implicit `JSON.stringify()` that `res.send` will run on it, leading to an unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: Ah, so by adding a `res` outside of the `POST` request it would skip to that. Removing it makes it wait for a response instead?

Comment: Yes. See, if you call the function out of the promise chain, it will not wait for the `axios` promise to resolve. BUT, you can call the `res.send` method from *inside* the callback function of the `.then` itself, which is called *only* when the promise successfully resolves.

Comment: You an also use async-await, which would make your asynchronous code *look* more imperative, but that's a whole other thread.